# TextField focus() not working

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

Using sample-Groceries-angular
I'm trying to focus password instead of email by clicking a button

```
┌──────────────────┬─────────────────┬────────────────┬───────────────┐
│ Component        │ Current version │ Latest version │ Information   │
│ nativescript     │ 2.3.0           │ 2.3.0          │ Up to date    │
│ tns-core-modules │ 2.3.0           │ 2.3.0          │ Up to date    │
│ tns-android      │ 2.3.0           │ 2.3.0          │ Up to date    │
│ tns-ios          │                 │ 2.3.0          │ Not installed │
└──────────────────┴─────────────────┴────────────────┴───────────────┘
```

xml:

```
<TextField #email hint="Email Address" keyboardType="email" [(ngModel)]="user.email"
autocorrect="false" autocapitalizationType="none"></TextField>
<TextField #password hint="Password" secure="true" [(ngModel)]="user.password"></TextField>
<Button text="Focus Password" (tap)="focusDat()"></Button>
```

typescript:

```
@ViewChild("password") password: ElementRef;
focusDat() {
  let password = <TextField>this.name.nativeElement;
  console.log(password.focus());
}
```

output:

```
JS: false
```

Comment: focus() only return if element or one of children has focus it won't set focus on textfield and bring out keyboard but you can go for native api to set textfield only problem you will need to do ios and android way separate

Comment: Well api says it tries to focus the view http://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_text_field_.textfield.html#focus is there a simple way of doing the same thing? :/

Comment: yea it tries to focus but not set it's test if there is softkeyboard visible and simple ? not sure because you need to do it per platform ios/android separately

Comment: Perhaps the problem is in the method, where you try to `focus` the field. Regarding to that to focus the password field try the following code in your method `this.password.nativeElement.focus();`

Comment: @NikolayTsonev method is okey it does what it should but it was misinterpreted focus() `return true/false` based on softkey visible or not and won't set focus on textfield

Comment: @NikolayTsonev LOL actually its working.. wow name instead of password.. i think i'm too tried xD Thanks and sorry =)

Comment: @AboAlwi would you mind posting that as an answer here and accepting just so others are aware without reading through this thread?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Nikolay Tsonev I just focused the wrong field 
was:

```
let password = <TextField>this.name.nativeElement;
```

should be:

```
let password = <TextField>this.password.nativeElement;
```

it's working fine, just made a silly mistake...

Answer (score 0):

you should refer this I tried to create OTP mech.

```
<TextField col="0" maxlength="1" (textChange)="o1()" verticalAlignment="center" style.placeholderColor="gray" [(ngModel)]="one" required #1ng="ngModel" returnKeyType="next" keyboardType="number"></TextField>
                <TextField col="1" maxlength="1" #b (textChange)="o2()" verticalAlignment="center" style.placeholderColor="gray" [(ngModel)]="two" required #2ng="ngModel" returnKeyType="next" keyboardType="number"></TextField>
                <TextField col="2" maxlength="1" #c (textChange)="o3()"verticalAlignment="center" style.placeholderColor="gray" [(ngModel)]="three" required #3ng="ngModel" returnKeyType="next" keyboardType="number"></TextField>
                <TextField col="3" maxlength="1" #d verticalAlignment="center" style.placeholderColor="gray" [(ngModel)]="four" required #4ng="ngModel" returnKeyType="done" keyboardType="number"></TextField>
```

.ts

```
    one=''
    two=''
    three=''
    four=''
    @ViewChild("b", { static: false }) b: ElementRef;
    @ViewChild("c", { static: false }) c: ElementRef;
    @ViewChild("d", { static: false }) d: ElementRef;

    o1(){
        this.b.nativeElement.focus()
    }

    o2(){
        this.c.nativeElement.focus()
    }

    o3(){
        this.d.nativeElement.focus()
    }
```